# Returning Last Value Assigned When Variables are Declared and Assigned on Different Lines

Tags: javascript, return, return-value, variable-declaration

I came across a strange issue with returns in JS, depending on whether my variables were declared and assigned in the same line or not. Perhaps someone can explain why this happens.

When I run this code (variables are declared and assigned in the same lines), it returns nothing, which makes sense because there is no return statement.

```
var hero = "lame";
var badguy = "strong";

if (hero === "strong") {
  if(badguy === "weak") {
    console.log("Awesome you won!");
  }
  console.log("You did not win.");
}
```

However, when I run this code (variables are declared and assigned on different lines), it returns "strong", which was the last variable to be assigned, even though there is no return statement. Why is this?

```
var hero, badguy;

hero = "lame";
badguy = "strong";

if (hero === "strong") {
  if(badguy === "weak") {
    console.log("Awesome you won!");
  }
  console.log("You did not win.");
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It doesn't return "strong", your if statement is not being executed. The result of the expression badguy = "strong" is being output.

Comment: badguy = "strong" is just assigning "strong" to badguy. There is no return statement, so why is "strong" being returned? How is it different from the first snippet of code? Thanks!

Comment: can you create a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vfsxtnf5/2/ - there is nothing returned

Comment: I assume you are running all of that in the console. In which case the console will display the value of the expression in the last statement executed. Which is the assignment, because the first if condition will be false. This behaviour in the console is not a "return"; it is not related to the concept of a `return` statement in a function.

Comment: I used both the console and repl.it. I am trying to find out why the console/repl.it is returning two different things (undefined vs. "strong") when I am assigning variables two different ways.

Comment: There is no function declaration or function call, the code is as-is. If you paste both of those into the console or repl.it as-is, you will either get nothing for the first code snippet, or "strong" for the second code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript (as well as some other languages) when you do an assignment, the value of that assignment gets returned automatically. Hence you can see it being logged by the console. Strange, I can't find a decent reference to this on the interwebs. This is the best I could find: http://www.sitepoint.com/assignment-inside-a-condition/

Comment: So why doesn't it return the value when the variable is declared and assigned in the same line?

Comment: Good question. In javascript we have expressions and statements. Expressions result in a value, a statement is a do something. So var x = "test"; means first, a space on disk is made and referenced by x. The initial value will be undefined. Then the = part does the assignment. I would hazzard a guess that undefined will be returned as that will be the first part of the expression.

Comment: Thanks! If anyone else has more information that would be awesome, but this basically explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please implement your function declaration and function call ?
I try the code below in browser console and both of them return undefined.

```
funcA = function() {
  var hero = "lame";
  var badguy = "strong";

  if (hero === "strong") {
    if(badguy === "weak") {
      console.log("Awesome you won!");
    }
    console.log("You did not win.");
  }
}

funcB = function() {
  var hero, badguy;

  hero = "lame";
  badguy = "strong";

  if (hero === "strong") {
    if(badguy === "weak") {
      console.log("Awesome you won!");
    }
    console.log("You did not win.");
  }
}

funcA(); // undefined
funcB(); // undefined
```

Comment: There is no function declaration or function call, the code is as-is. If you paste both of those into the console or repl.it as-is, you will either get nothing for the first code snippet, or "strong" for the second code snippet.